# UserManager.RemoveFromRoles not removing the roles

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult EditUser(AspNetUser UserToEdit, string[] roles)
        {
            AspNetUser CurrentUser = db.AspNetUsers.Find(User.Identity.GetUserId());
            AspNetUser UserBeingEdited = db.AspNetUsers.Find(UserToEdit.Id);

            string[] AllRoles = db.AspNetRoles.Select(s => s.Name).ToArray();
            UserManager.RemoveFromRoles(UserBeingEdited.Id, AllRoles);


            // Add all of the roles returned from the webpage
            if (roles.Count() > 0)
            {
                UserManager.AddToRoles(UserBeingEdited.Id, roles);
            }
        }
```

After I run this code I check the user and the user still has the same roles they had before.   roles is a list of roles returned from my edit user page and it is populated correctly.

Anyone know how to get this to work?  No errors or anything.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think that problem is when you are removing user from all available roles, not from roles that user has.

Try this,

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult EditUser(AspNetUser UserToEdit, string[] roles)
    {
        // Get user roles
        string[] allUserRoles = UserManager.GetRoles(UserToEdit.Id).ToArray();
        UserManager.RemoveFromRoles(UserToEdit.Id, allUserRoles);

        // Add all of the roles returned from the webpage
        if (roles.Count() > 0)
        {
            UserManager.AddToRoles(UserToEdit.Id, roles);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This did fix it, tho I wish I would have read here before testing numerous different things and coming to the same conclusion. :)  For some reason it wouldn't remove -any- roles if the list contained roles they were not a part of.  When I provide a list of roles they have it removes them just fine.