# Mapping only valid custom user roles to a user

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I want to map only valid userroles to a user.  This line of code using property is throwing an error because it's not allowing me to use linq here.... its just an example of what I'd like to try to accomplish.

Right now (without the where clause) it returns all userroles records with invalid being 0 and 1.  My goal is to get ONLY userroles records where invalid is 0 (false).

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {      
        modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUserRole>().ToTable("AspNetUserRoles", "dbo").Where(u => !u.Invalid); 

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);                             
    }
}
```

DB schema (note added invalid col):

[image]

Comment: What error, where is your problem. Elaborate we don't sit in your mind.

Comment: @TomaszJuszczak Well, essentially the error isn't the issue.  I'm just trying to map ONLY records from AspNetUserRoles table that have a value of false (or 0 in db since it's a bit) for the Invalid column in that table.  That's where I'm stuck.

Comment: [Interceptors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469464(v=vs.113).aspx) might be one way. Not sure how that's going to get along with Identity. If it is just this one table look at handling it further down in the repository or controller.

Comment: @SteveGreene It's three tables, but I'm just focusing on this one in particular for now.   Example, UserA is setup with admin role.  Then we change UserA to have only Basic role.  In this scenario, we'd set invalid to true for the userrole record for this user and admin role, then add the new Basic role with invalid to false.  Problem right now is it adds both roles to user. I figured this would be a common scenario, and like you said, I may need to do this elsewhere instead of the mapper.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just remove the user from those roles like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35439357/usermanager-removefromroles-not-removing-the-roles).

Comment: @SteveGreene this is the point I am at.  I'm going to post my code later on today.  However, yes, this is a solution.  But wouldn't it be better to filter out from the beginning?

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding your requirement. You have users. You have roles. When a user changes roles, you remove them from old role(s) in the junction table and add them to the new one(s). Unless it is important for you to see prior roles or something, I don't see the need for a soft delete.

Comment: @SteveGreene I agree on the soft delete, but the db is out of my jurisdiction. When a user logins in, they can have multiple roles.  This is ok, but upon login it returns the valid AND invalid ones. The soft delete really isn't that bad, I just need to assign the user only valid roles.  I figured it would be a bit easier than this.

Answer (score 0):

I never could find a proper solution to this my exact problem, so instead of using softdeletes for the dbo.AspNetUserRole table I changed it to hard deletes.  Now when logging in, Identity still returns all roles for that user, it just doesn't have any "Invalid" ones anymore.